# How to export an InDesign file to PDF that is going to be spiral bound

Tags: adobe-indesign, print-design, pdf, export

Ok so I designed a 106 page cookbook that is going to be spiral bounded.

I created my InDesign document with a **3mm bleed** and **facing pages.**

On some pages there is an image that is stretched between two spreads, and some full bleed images.

My question now is how do I export this to PDF to send it to the printers.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same way you'd export any print-destined file. Export as single page, PDF/X-1a with bleeds and marks.

Be aware, you *really* want *large* inner margins for any type of spiral or comb binding. And spanning images across the gutter *may* result in misaligned images. It's generally not a great idea to span across the gutter when spiral or comb binding.

Comment: Should it be exported as spreads or single pages. Because when I use single pages with bleeds and marks, it _pushes_ some design from the right page onto the left page (i.e about 5mm of the design from the left side of page 3 will display on the right side of page 2)

Comment: If you have your job set up as facing pages, set your inner bleeds to zero before exporting as single pages.

Comment: **DO NOT** set inner bleeds to 0 **ever** unless your print provider *specifically* asks you to. If it is to be spiral/comb bound, **export as single pages**, and seeing the bleed from the left page outside the crops of the right page is standard. In other words, you **should** see gutter content on opposite pages when viewing the PDF/X file.